# Errors with \printbibliography in BibLatex using biber

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I am a newbie to Latex and I have to write a paper for school where I have to cite different sources. I tried to read up on how to make a bibliography and came to the conclusion that I should use `BibLatex` using `biber` as the backend because it is newer and more flexible.

However when I try to use `BibLatex` with `biber` do not get a bibliography when I use `\printbibliography` and i get 3 errors

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.6)
The top-level auxiliary file: diho.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file diho.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file diho.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file diho.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

This is weird because I do not use `bibtex` as the backend. I then tried using `bibtex`as the backend and it worked as anticipated.

This is my code when using `biber`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{uni.bib}

\begin{document}
    \title{Efterkrigstid og Albert Camus}
    \author{Rasmus Enevoldsen}
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introdution}
    \parencite{Camus42} 
    \blindtext
    \parencite{Seeberg62}
    
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

And my .bib file

```
@articel{Camus42,
author =    "Albert Camus",
title =     "Le Mythe de Sisyphe. (Fransk) [Sisyfos-myten]",
year =      "1942"
    
}
@incollection{Seeberg62,
    author =    "Seeberg, Peter",
    title =     "Hjulet",
    booktitle = "eftersøgningen og andre noveller",
    isbn =      "9788702234862",
    year =      "1962"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Thanks for providing an MWE. Actually there are no fatal problems with your code. I suspect that the error you are getting is because of compiling with a wrong program. The error isn't because of `\printbibliography` it is because you are using `bibtex`, while your backend should be `biber`. The first line of the log snippet you posted says that "This is BibTeX". So please compile with the correct program.

Comment: The log file shown above is from a BibTeX run and not a Biber run. But you need to compile your document with Biber and not with BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with making your editor run Biber for you. (See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 for a short discussion of BibTeX vs Biber and what they do. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for a longer discussion of what BibTeX/Biber do.)

Comment: The minor (and non-fatal) errors you have made are 1) Writing `articel` instead of `article`. 2) Using an old syntax i.e. `article = "<name>"`. You might want to adopt the new syntax `article={<name>}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code with some minor enhancements.

1. Use `@article` instead of `@articel`
2. Use the modern syntax with curly braces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{uni.bib}
@article{Camus42,
  author = {Albert Camus},
  title  = {Le Mythe de Sisyphe. (Fransk) [Sisyfos-myten]},
  year   = {1942}  
}
@incollection{Seeberg62,
  author    = {Seeberg, Peter},
  title     = {Hjulet},
  booktitle = {eftersøgningen og andre noveller},
  isbn      = {9788702234862},
  year      = {1962}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{uni.bib}
\title{Efterkrigstid og Albert Camus}
\author{Rasmus Enevoldsen}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introdution}
\parencite{Camus42} 

\blindtext

\parencite{Seeberg62}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compile this in the following order.

```bash
pdflatex filename.tex
biber filename # note that I have avoided .tex extension
pdflatex filename.tex
pdflatex filename.tex
```